# A space-efficient view

Tags: view, couchdb

For all documents with a certain `type` I have a single query in my app, which selects just a single field of the last document. I map those documents by date, so making a descending query limited to 1 should certainly do the trick. The problem I'm bothered by is that this view would cache all documents of this type, occupying an obviously redundant space.

So my questions are:

1. Would adding a reduce function, which would reduce to the single last document, to this view save any space for me or the view would still have to store all the documents involved?
2. If not, is there any other space-efficient strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. Space will still be wasted by the result of map function.
2. Some things in my mind at the moment:

   - Change the design of the database. If the id of the document will include the type and date you could do some searching without the map/reduce like this: `http://127.0.0.1:5984/YOURDB/_all_docs?start_key="<TYPE>_<CURRENT_TIME>"&descending=true&limit=1`.
   - Make use of `map` the best you can. Emit no value, and map will store the key and the id/ver of the documents. Use `include_doc` to retrieve the doc when querying.
   - Add additional field saying that the document is a candidate for the last one. Map only those candidates who does have the field. Periodically run cleanup, removing the field from all the documents except the latest one. Note: this can by difficult when deleting the last added document is supported.

That seems to be for me the idea of CouchDB: "waste" space by caching the queries, so they can by answered quickly if the data is not changing to frequently. Perhaps if you care so much about wasting the space, the answer in your case in not the CouchDB?

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you! I'm a bit bound to Couch since I'm using Cloudant as an in-cloud db-hoster. Which NoSQL alternative would you suggest? A suggestion on alternative service to Cloudant in that case would be even better.

Comment: Note that, whatever DB system you will choose the query you want will be terribly slow if you do not create index with the fields `type` and `date`. You can consider the map that filters on the `type` and returns the key date and no value as the index. It may be more space efficient then any other DB. Problem of Couch is that it is difficult to make thinks that are not efficient: no joins, no searching without index, etc.

Comment: I really like all your suggestions, very witty. Another question: isn't the id of form `<TYPE>_<CURRENT_TIME>` based query going to be the slowest? Wouldn't it have to go through all the document ids down until it to find it?

Comment: And... unfortunately, I do not have a suggestion for something other than Cloudant, as all my apps are running on our servers.

Comment: Also do I understand you correctly that to prefer the ids of form "type-date" to having a separate `type`-field is your general recommendation?

Comment: I think querying `_all_docs` should be quick. I do not know its implementation, but the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#all_docs) suggest it is (implicit) view. Standard view (like map) keeps all the data in the B-Tree and you should be able to search it fast. I think you should ask new question about it, so someone more familiar with CouchDB internals will answer it :)

Comment: In general, it is usually good to use ids that represents some usable value, but everything depends on you specific case. I am not familiar in all your DB design to make to specific suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

My couchdb setup has the data and the indexes on sperate RAID drives. Maps are written in erlang which I find 8x faster  faster than javascript and maps of course return null. I keep the keys small and  I also break up my views across many design documents and I keep my data very flat which improves serialization performance.